# conversation numbers corrupted after restoring

Tags: iphone, messages, restore

I restored my new Phone from the itunes back up using the iSkysoft due to lack of storage (selective restore). After restoring I wasnt able to send messages to anyone, later turned out that numbers have been corrupted. In the below image the number should be either `0346 3897737` Or `+923463897373` but it missed the `0` at the beginning. 
I tried again and again, but every time it has the same problem.
Is there any way I can get them back.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like something iSkysoft would need to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.